# Problem playing audio file with AVAudioPlayer on iPhone 4 in iOS 4.1

Tags: xcode, ios4, avaudioplayer, iphone-4

I am using a simple bit of code to play an audio file:

```
NSString *pathToMusicFile1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song" ofType:@"mp3"];
mySong1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMusicFile1] error:NULL]; 
NSLog(@"Song1 Loaded");
mySong1.numberOfLoops = -1;
mySong1.volume = 1.0;
[mySong1 play];
```

I have imported AVFoundation and I have declared mySong1 in my header file and then synthesized it in my implementation file.  This code works fine, for the most part.  I get no errors and the audio plays great in the simulator.  It also plays fine on an iPhone 3GS running 4.0 and on an original iPhone running 3.1.3.  The problem is that it doesn't play on an iPhone 4 running iOS 4.1.  I have tried cleaning the project as well as restarting the phone.  Neither helps.  I also tried an .aiff file instead of the mp3, but no luck there either.

What am I missing?  Is there an alternative way to play sounds that I should be using now?  Any help appreciated.  Can't figure out what the problem is here.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try running it under a debugger in iPhone 4, running iOS 4.1.1., what is the error message?

Comment: No error message. Just no sound.  That's what's strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I’m pretty embarrassed to have to post this, but my phone was set to silent mode - which is why I wasn't getting any audio from my app on my phone.  Maybe my mistake helps someone else?  Hope so.  Just cost me a few hours to figure that out. GAH!